# Join then Distinct Count

Tags: sql, oracle

. I need to find only Employees that are type A. I know this can be done with a JOIN. Then I need to get a count of all distinct EMP_ID for each Region.Also note this will be done in Oracle

Comment: For the final output I want to have a list of all the Regions in one Column and a count of distinct EMP_IDs for that region in the COL beside it. COUNT(distinct EMP_ID) gives me a count of all distinct ids but not by Region.

Comment: You are looking for employees who have *any* job code in type A? If they have both type A and type B, they should be counted? If they have multiple type A in a given region, they should be counted once for that region?

Comment: Please post the query you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are basic things, you need `join` and condition on the table containing `type = 'A'`:

```
select count(distinct emp_id)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.job_code = t2.job_code
where t2.type = 'A'
group by t1.region
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a CTE.

```
With someCte
as
(
Select * from table1 t1
Inner join table2 t2 on t1.Job_code = t2.Job_code
where t1.type like 'A' and t2.type like 'A'
)
select distinct emp_id from someCte
```